# Chat cookies does not work, how to fix problem?

Tags: javascript, cookies

I has a problem with cookies on chat. If i close the chat, cookies must be write, and when i open chat, it must renew. I has a code:

```
var chats = $.cookie('chats');
if (chats == 'on')
{
    $('#chatshow').addClass('hidden');
    $('#chathide').removeClass('hidden');
    $('.chat-body').animate(
    {
        height: '500px'
    }, 1000);
    $('.chat-footer').animate(
    {
        height: '55px'
    }, 500)
}
else
{
    $('#chatshow').removeClass('hidden');
    $('#chathide').addClass('hidden');
    $('.chat-body').animate(
    {
        height: '0px'
    }, 200);
    $('.chat-footer').animate(
    {
        height: '0px'
    }, 200)
};


$(document).on('click', '#chathide', function (e)
{
    e.preventDefault();
    $('#chatshow').removeClass('hidden');
    $('#chathide').addClass('hidden');
    $('.subchat').slideUp();
    $('.chat-body').animate(
    {
        height: '0px'
    }, 1000);
    $('.chat-footer').animate(
    {
        height: '0px'
    }, 500);
    chats = 'off';
    $.cookie('chats', 'off', {
        expires: 365
    })
});
$(document).on('click', '#chatshow', function (e)
{
    e.preventDefault();
    $('#chatshow').addClass('hidden');
    $('#chathide').removeClass('hidden');
    $('.chat-body').animate(
    {
        height: '500px'
    }, 1000);
    $('.chat-footer').animate(
    {
        height: '55px'
    }, 500);
    chats = 'on';
    $.cookie('chats', 'on', {
        expires: 365
    })
});
```

And in the socket of chat i use `var chats = $.cookie('chats');`, all must be good. But, my browser is save the cookies (i see cookie with parameter `off`), but when i close chat, after refresh page chat don't close. And in the dev.console says: ``` A cookie associated with a cross-site resource at <URL> was set without the ``SameSite`` attribute. A future release of Chrome will only deliver cookies with cross-site requests if they are set with ``SameSite=None`` and ``Secure``. You can review cookies in developer tools under Application>Storage>Cookies and see more details at <URL> and <URL>. ```.

Where is my mistake? What's wrong?

Comment: I would need more information to help here. Where and how are you setting the cookie? What's the context where this code is running? Is it in the top-level page or embedded on another site via an iframe.